# cartthrob make shipping optional

Tags: cartthrob, shipping

Has anyone ever seen the ability to make shipping optional in Cart Throb?  What I am looking for is an option to have an order shipped or pick it up in store and not pay the shipping cost?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this would be possible, but it would likely involve creating a shipping plugin.

You could save custom order or item data when adding a product to the cart. And your shipping plugin would check if that data exists and return 0 if it does.

https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/developers/shipping_plugins/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As long as the alternative method of shipping is simple enough, we usually use the **Customer Selectable Flat Rates** shipping method to allow for this option.

One of our clients has the default set to Standard with a flat shipping fee, but also an additional option for Pick Up in Store at no cost. You could also add in other options for Ground, Express, 2-day, etc.

If the alternative method of shipping is more complicated such as live rates or By Location/Weight, we then create a custom plugin based on their preferred shipping plugin but simply adding in Pick Up in Store to the array of options manually.